# How to correctly work with mailing lists?

Tags: mailing-list

Mailing lists are preffered communication channel for many open source products. But what is the best ways to interact with mailing lists? Currently i just receive a digest 2-3 times a day to my gmail account. This is not very good since i can't see tree-view structure of discussion and can't answer specific discussion branches. Alse, it's hard to maintain any notifications. For example, python mailing list emerges over 100 messages per day that are all packed into a few digest. If i'm interested only in 1-2 discussions taking place, it's no way for me to be notified about new messages in this discussions - i need to manually check every digest / e-mail and guess who answers what message and what is a discussion structure.

Maybe it's some desktop / web apps exists that allows to work with mailing list as with a standard tree-iew forum structure with notifications etc? Or is it some arcane methodology that provides an easy way to work with them? I feel myself terribly ineffictive with mailing lists right now :(

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @leppie: Many open source programming projects use mailing lists as a main communication channel with developers. So working with mailing lists is a skill that is required for developers. Same as with debuggr, make tool or your favorite IDE. Unforyunately, there is thery little amount of mailing lists info in google. It seems that they are "so obvious to use that no info is needed" - but they are definitely not. So i'm asking this question to check if i miss some essential tool knowledge or this tool is a crap that everyone uses due to tradition :)

Comment: @leppie: IronScheme has a discussion forum on codeplex, so you are in much better position than myself. Due to my work i need to monitor python, wix and some other minor open source projects. And they use mailing lists :(.

Comment: IF the answer does not involve code, it is not a programming question. Try superuser or programmers.stackexchange rather then. I dont mean to be rude, just SO is getting full of irrelevant content.

Comment: @leppie: Unfortunately, i can't share your opinion. Questions about IDE, debuggers or architecture don't involve code. Still, they are programming questions. I think there are better targets for your holy crusade tovards irrelevant content ^_^. Anyway, your top question, "What do you do when your team leader doesn't know something simple?" doesn't contain any code and is more irrelevant than my question.

Comment: I agree that that question does belong on programmers.stackexchange, but that site did not exist when I posted it  :)

Comment: @leppie: is it any statistics on users/question/answers per day for mothership "stackoverflow" and satellite .stackexchange sites? I fear that programmers.stackexchange has a much more narrowed audience and my question will be unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your problem in three easy steps:

- Set up the mail-filtering capabilities of your mail client to store mail from each list to a separate folder. You could also use something like `procmail` on Unix-like systems.
- Use the threading feature of your mail client so that you can follow discussions.
- Set up your mailing list subscriptions, so that you receive individual messages, rather than digests. Digests are quite harder for you (and your mail client) to handle. They also frustrate *us* when you reply to the digest, rather than the individual message, thus breaking the threading in our mail clients.

Comment: Any guides how to configure gmail this way, or i need to use some desktop client like thunderbird?

Comment: @Eye of Hell: gmail is supposed to support quite extensive mail filtering, but I have never used it. I prefer to use local mail clients instead.